# Flutter Await Callback Not Give Any Response

Tags: dart, async-await, flutter

I am still a beginner on dart flutter, now I am trying to retrieve data from the REST API and socket.IO. at this time I have a confusing problem, I have tried searching on the internet for 3 days, but there is no solution. I have async and await scripts, but the function I added await doesn't give any response and still pause.

it is assumed that I have two different files, the first is the main file and the second is the helper file.

**main.dart**

```
Future<List<ChatTile>> fetchChat(socketutil,id) async {

  socketutil.join(id); //STACK IN HERE
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String messagePrefs = prefs.getString('messagePrefs');
  print("DUA");
  return await compute(parseListChat, messagePrefs);
}
```

**helper.dart**

```
Future<void> join(String id_room) async {
      String jsonData ='{"room_id" : "$id_room","user_id" : "5a91687811138e74009839c9","user_name" : "Denis Muhammad Ramdan","user_photo" : "photo.jpg","user_status" : "1"}';
      socketIO.sendMessage("join", jsonData, null);
      //subscribe event
      return await socketIO.subscribe("updateMessageList", (result) async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await prefs.setString('messagePrefs', result);
        print('SATU');
        return await result;
      });
  }
```

**my  question is there something wrong with my code, and how is the best way?**

many thanks,

Comment: Looks like you expect `return await result;` to return from `join(...)` which is not what it does. It just returns from the callback you passed to `subscribe(...)`.
I don't know what `socketIO` is exactly or what `socketIO.subscribe()` returns but subscribe sounds like the returned Future may only return when the connection is closed which probably is never and this is why `compute()` never completes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Günter Zöchbauer , I have tried adding `await` `behind socketutil.join (id);` be like this await `socketutil.join (id);` but the code still pause and does not continue the next execution. What is the best way to handle this case?

Comment: As I said I don't know what `socketIO.subscribe()` returns, so it's hard to make suggestions. My assumption is that `socketIO.subscribe()` never completes so awaiting that won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add `await_only_futures` to your analyzer config

analysis_options.yaml

```
lint:
  rules:
   - await_only_futures
```

You also don't need to do `return await something` since your function already return a future, this is redondant.

And from what I see of the socketio subscribe method, it does not return the result like you expect but use a callback and does not return it (https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_socket_io/latest/flutter_socket_io/SocketIO/subscribe.html)

to handle this you should use a [`Completer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html)

```
final completer = Completer<String>()

socketIO.subscribe("updateMessageList", (result) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('messagePrefs', result);
    socketIO.unSubscribe("updateMessageList");
    completer.complete(result);
  });

return completer.future;
```

you probably want to handle error when there is using `completer.completeError(error)`

### Update

You can alos convert the subscription to a Dart Stream to handle more case.

```
StreamController<String> controller;

Stream<String> get onUpdateMessageList {
   if (controller != null) return controller.stream;

   constroller = StreamController<String>.broadcast(
     onCancel: () => socketIO.unSubscribe("updateMessageList"),
   );

   socketIO.subscribe("updateMessageList", constroller.add);

   return controller.stream;
}



Future<StreamSubscription> join(String id_room) async {
  ...
  return onUpdateMessageList.listen((result) async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await prefs.setString('messagePrefs', result);
  });
}
```

Comment: Is the callback passed to `subscribe` only called once? If it is called more than once then I assume there should be unsubscribe be called somewhere as well.

Comment: indeed, if you only want one result, you have to unsubscribe the event, I will update

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer and @Hadrien Lejard the `subscribe` can be called several times.

Comment: @DenisRamdan in your `fetchChat` function, do you want to update Shared preferences each time you have an `updateMessageList` or just one time then execute the rest of your function ?

Comment: I update my example and hope I gave you all blocs (Completer, Future, Stream) that could help you

Comment: many thanks for all of you who have commented and helped. _terimakasih banyak_